# Error Tensorflow Couldn't find field google.protobuf.EnumDescriptorProto.EnumReservedRange.start

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, tensorflow

Hi I'm trying running an tensorflow application in my computer.
I installed the tf , using the pip  and follow the steps in the tensorflows documentation.

I'm using python 3.6.3 in ubuntu 17.10

```
KeyError: "Couldn't find field google.protobuf.EnumDescriptorProto.EnumReservedRange.start"
```

Tks

Comment: Can you show us the code you have that created this error?

Comment: `import tensorflow as tf`


`print("Hello TensorFlow version", tf.__Version__)`
`print()`

Answer (score 1):

I get this error when I try to use TensorFlow with Anaconda rather than Python 2.7 on a Mac.  To see if you are using Anaconda, use the **which** command:

> which python
>
> - /Users/me/anaconda2/bin/python

If this is causing your problem, the solution is to install Tensorflow in a virtual environment:

> export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:$PATH which python
>
> - /usr/bin/python
>
> cd
>
> virtualenv tf
>
> source ~/tf/bin/activate
>
> pip install tensorflow

To use tensorflow in the future, remember that you must first activate the venv (**source ~/tf/bin/activate**.)